# google map api chart

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table and also some query for the fusion table.Now i want to create dynamic pie chart for each query.Values for the pie chart should be taken from two select box.How to do this.There are three html div element in my webpage.one for rendering map,other for fusion table visualization and next one is for chart data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial about [how to query Google Fusion Tables with Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/fusiontables).

Here is an example:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

function drawFTChart() {
  google.visualization.drawChart({
    "containerId": "my_chart_div",
    "dataSourceUrl": 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=',
    "query":"SELECT Location,Number FROM 1R9FMod3LN7UO3R6jp7gJeSQ9hbEVOwLqF0AZFQg",
    "refreshInterval": 5,
    "chartType": "PieChart",
    "options": {
      "title":"Number distribution over cities"
    }
  });
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawFTChart);
```